# QGIS - Windows 11 problem?

Tags: qgis, windows

I installed the QGIS version 3.22 on my Windows 11 computer.

I have problems with the "Browser" because I can't use "WCS resources" in my projects.

Anyone knows how to fix it? Is it a common problem?

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain in detail what you mean with <<I can't use "WCS resources">>?